# Vectorize groupedby dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe where one of the columns is `item` and there is a non-unique field `id`. So first, I'm grouping by `id`:

```
grouped = df.groupby('id')
```

Now I can iterate each group like so:

```
for name, group in grouped:
```

I can also have a list of all unique items with

```
all_items = df['item'].unique()
```

What I'd like to do is for each group get a list/vector of size `len(all_items)` with counts according to the number of times the `item` appeared in the group. Basically, my main goal is to have a numpy matrix of these vectors so I can process it with scikit-learn models.

How can I do that?

Comment: do you mean `pd.crosstab(df['id'],df['item'])` ? can you show us a small example and an expected output?

Comment: Exactly what I meant! Thanks @anky (You may write this as an answer if you'd like)

Comment: It has been asked before actually , hence closing :-) Glad my comment helped you..!!